# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY The conflict occurred in database "HRDATABASE", table "dbo.Countries", column 'country_id'

Tags: sql

I get this error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Locations__Count__4222D4EF". The conflict occurred in database "HRDATABASE", table "dbo.Countries", column 'country_id'.

My code:

```
CREATE DATABASE HRDATABASE

USE HRDATABASE

CREATE Table Regions
(
    Region_ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Region_Name VARCHAR(35) DEFAULT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Regions(Region_ID,Region_Name) VALUES(1,'Europe');
INSERT INTO Regions(Region_ID,Region_Name) VALUES(2,'USA');
INSERT INTO Regions(Region_ID,Region_Name) VALUES(3,'ITALY');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Regions ON;

CREATE TABLE Countries
(
    Country_id CHAR (2) PRIMARY KEY,
    Country_name VARCHAR (40) DEFAULT NULL,
    Region_id INT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (region_id) REFERENCES regions (region_id) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO countries (Country_id, Country_name, Region_id) 
VALUES ('AR', 'Argentina', 2);
INSERT INTO countries (Country_id, Country_name, Region_id) 
VALUES ('AU', 'Australia', 3);
INSERT INTO countries (Country_id, Country_name, Region_id) 
VALUES ('BE', 'Belgium', 1);

CREATE TABLE Locations
(
    Location_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Street_Address VARCHAR (40) DEFAULT NULL,
    Postal_Code VARCHAR (12) DEFAULT NULL,
    City VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    State_Province VARCHAR (25) DEFAULT NULL,
    Country_ID CHAR (2) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries (country_id) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT locations ON;

INSERT INTO Locations (Location_ID, Street_Address, Postal_Code, City, State_Province, Country_ID) 
VALUES (1400, '2014 Jabberwocky Rd', '26192', 'Southlake', 'Texas', 'US');
INSERT INTO Locations (Location_ID, Street_Address, Postal_Code, City, State_Province, Country_ID) 
VALUES (1500, '2011 Interiors Blvd', '99236', 'South San Francisco', 'California', 'US');
INSERT INTO Locations (Location_ID, Street_Address, Postal_Code, City, State_Province, Country_ID) 
VALUES (1700, '2004 Charade Rd', '98199', 'Seattle', 'Washington', 'US');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT locations OFF;
```

Comment: You don't have `Country_Id` of "US" in the `Countries` table while you are trying to refer to in `locations`

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting the `country_id` "US" in your locations table, however you don't have that `country_id` in your countries table.

Either insert a "US" country in countries or remove your foreign key constrait on Locations table `FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries (country_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`